# How to change size of two divs relatively

Tags: html, css, plotly, plotly-dash

I have two divs next to each other as shown in the image. I want to show the other div/Graph in  full screen that's why I used collapse feature.
Now when I collapse one div the other div's size should be 100% or full screen. I don't know how can I achieve this.

**PS: I am using plotly-dash.**

These are the images of the divs.
[image: IMG 1]
[image: IMG 2]

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `flexbox` and let the left box fill the remaining space with `flex-grow`:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.right {
  width: min-content;
  padding: 10px;
}




/* for styling purpose only */
.left {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.right {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right">
    <textarea></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```